# Integrable systems and algebraic geometry

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, dynamical-systems, integrable-systems

Could you recommend a good book to study integrable systems? I want it to be from the point of view of algebraic geometry.

Comment: What level are you aiming at?  advanced? beginner?

Comment: Beginner. I read partially the following book
http://books.google.ru/books/about/Solitons.html?id=kQDw1ZcqLjUC&redir_esc=y

Comment: @user46336 I very much recommend Hitchin part of [this book](http://www.amazon.com/gp/reader/0198504217/ref=sib_dp_pt#reader-link). Its scanned version can be found on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this reference ["Integrable Systems in the Realm of Algebraic Geometry"](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/dynamical+systems/book/978-3-540-42337-9) (Vanhaecke, 2001) may be of use.  This book is a series of lecture notes.  ["Integrable Systems"](http://www.mi.ras.ru/~snovikov/98.pdf) (Dubrovin et al.) is a book completely available online.

Hope these are of some help.